# Replacing font-awesome icon with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, icons, font-awesome

I am want to replace a icon (Font Awesome) with an other.
I try this :

```js
const toolbar1 = document.querySelector("#toolbar1");
  const iconToReplace = toolbar1.querySelector(".fa fa-arrows-alt");
  iconToReplace.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-fa-compress"></i>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it didn't work.
Is there a solution?
Thanks !

Comment: You want ***el.classList.add/remove***

Comment: `innerHTML` is the ...well.. *inner* HTML - ie what's inside the element - eg `<i class='fa'>THIS BIT</i>` you probably wanted the `outerHTML`

Comment: `$("#toolbar1 .fa-arrows-alt").removeClass("fa-arrows-alt").addClass("fa-compress")`  - adding `class='fa-fa-compress` should also *probably* have been `class='fa fa-compress'` - you seem to be mixing classnames with selectors

Answer (score 0):

Your selector within the `.querySelector()` call seems invalid, it should be:

```js
const iconToReplace = toolbar1.querySelector(".fa.fa-arrows-alt");
```

Furthermore, depending on the structure of the HTML, you may have intended to replace the class name of the selected element, instead of replacing the inner content of it:

```js
iconToReplace.classList.remove('fa-arrows-alt');
iconToReplace.classList.add('fa-compress');
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const toolbar1 = document.querySelector("#toolbar1");
  const iconToReplace = toolbar1.querySelector(".fa.fa-arrows-alt");
  iconToReplace.classList.remove('fa-arrows-alt');
  iconToReplace.classList.add('fa-compress');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="toolbar1"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></div>
<button>Run</button>
```

Also, you are not actually using jQuery at all in your code – is it a requirement to use it?

Comment: What if user has multiple classes in the icon? className will replace the entire string in the ***class*** attribute. Perhaps you should incorporate classList into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update the below code with your code.

```
const toolbar1 = $("#toolbar1");
const iconToReplace = toolbar1.find(".fa.fa-arrows-alt");
iconToReplace.html('<i class="fa fa-compress"></i>');
```